# R: extracting files using dir() function with pattern being identified in a matrix

Tags: r, data.table

I am currently trying to create a function that will extract file paths located in a specific directory. These files are extracted if the pattern identified in the dir() function is present within a specific filepath. Each pattern that I am looking for is stored within a matrix. There are multiple files associated with each pattern. I am currently testing this function on 2 file names, but will be adding on several more once it is up and running.

I am running into two issues within this approach:

1. I don't believe the pattern being pulled from the matrix is identified as a string in the dir() function (path=data_sets[i,2]) - there are no quotes around it.
2. I receive the error : "replacement has length zero" (This may be related to the first error I listed above but am unsure).

I am wondering if someone can help me turn the pattern column within my matrix into a string that will be recognized as a pattern within the dir() function in my code or alternatively, identify an easier way to get the end result.

Here's the code I am currently using:

```
data_sets<-c("data1", "data2")

extract_most_recent_files_to_source<-function(data_sets){
  
data_sets<-as.data.table(data_sets)
data_sets[, pattern:=paste0("\"^[", data_sets, "]\"")]
data_sets[, pattern:=gsub("\\\\", "", pattern )]
data_sets<-as.matrix(data_sets)

df_mod<-do.call("rbind", lapply(1:nrow(data_sets), function(i){
files<-dir("filepath", pattern = as.character(data_sets[i,2]), full.names = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
files<-as.data.table(files)
return(files)
}))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but 
`data_sets[i,1]<-as.data.table(data_sets[i,1])` can't be working - assuming you're using the `data.table` package, `as.data.table` returns a type of `data.frame`. Data frames can't be vectorised, so they can't be the elements of matrices.

Comment: @CaptainHat Thanks for pointing this out. I was originally trying to take the name stored in the matrix and point it to the table, but you are absolutely correct. I've updated the code above so that "files" points to the vector and table.